# How to append elements into an array from another View Controller in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, uitableview

Hello guys I have a question about append a new element into an array everytime i pressed a button. I have two View Controllers, the first one "RegisterViewController", that contains a textfield and a button.

```
@IBAction func didTapSave(_ sender: UIButton) {
    usernameText.endEditing(true)
    userText = usernameText.text ?? ""
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToData", sender: self)    
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "goToData" {
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as! UserTableViewController
        destinationVC.userData = userText
        destinationVC.saveItems()
}
```

The idea is to add the texfield.text to a tableView that is in the SecondViewcontroller

by far I can append one textfield.text, then when I go back to RegisterViewController and try again with a different text, the array that i use for the tableView just "edits" that last string but doesnt add another element.

When i print the itemArray.count it's always 0 that means there's only one text, but doesnt add the other ones if i continue writing on the textfield

```
class UserTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource { 
    var userData : String?
    var itemArray = [Item]()
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        saveItems()
    }
    func saveItems() {
        let newItem = Item(userRegister: userData ?? "")
        itemArray.append(newItem)
        print(itemArray.count)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason there is that every time you load the `UserTableViewController` you are creating a new itemArray. The easiest way to solve this issue is to make `RegisterViewController` your table view data source and delegate. You just need to pass the register view controller instance to your tableview instead of passing the `userData`. Try like this:

```
class RegisterViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var usernameText: UITextField!
    var items: [Item] = []
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        items.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellID", for: indexPath)
        var content = cell.defaultContentConfiguration()
        content.text = items[indexPath.row].userRegister
        cell.contentConfiguration = content
        return cell
    }
    @IBAction func didTapSave(_ sender: Any) {
        usernameText.endEditing(true)
        items.append(.init(userRegister: usernameText.text!))
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToData", sender: self)
    }
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "goToData" {
            let destinationVC = segue.destination as! UserTableViewController
            destinationVC.registerViewController = self
        }
    }
}
```

---

And your UserTableViewController:

```
class UserTableViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var registerViewController: RegisterViewController?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()   
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellID")
        tableView.delegate = registerViewController
        tableView.dataSource = registerViewController
    }
}
```